# Ubuntu doesnt load after installing windows 7

Tags: boot, dual-boot, windows-7, ntfs, drive

Installed windows 7 on my hp-15r014tx.
I had installed ubuntu before .
after lot of struggle. I partitioned my hardisk into two parts.
500 GB NTFS(For windows) and 400 GB ext4(for linux) and some remaining space unallocated and some space reserved by system.
As soon as I successfully installed windows 7 ultimate 64 bit, in the 500 GB NTFS partition, my system stop recognizing ubuntu and automatically loads only windows , and also the other 400 gb which is ext4 is not being recognized in windows.
and I used the linux live cd everything works perfect there, and also all three drives are being recognized including ntfs windows and ext4 linux which I can only touch them using root. 
I am quite new to all this and I want to dual boot windows and linux.
And also is there any possible way that windows recognizes the ext4 drive as a hardrive or any other application so I can access both drives in windows. Linux however recognizes both the drives.
Thank you for reading and please help, Sorry to sound dumb but I am really new to all this .

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This must've been asked a million times on the site, but some quick searching didn't reveal the questions I know are here.

The short answers are:

- Windows likes to pretend it's the only OS in the world, so installing it will always break any existing OS installs (next time, install Ubuntu last).
- Windows will never recognize an ext4 partition (but Ubuntu will recognize NTFS just fine)

In any case, unless you told Windows to actually wipe it off the disk, Ubuntu is still there; you just need to re-set up the boot record/menu:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows

**Update**
As for accessing the linux partition from Windows, that is a question that's been asked on [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/37512/how-to-read-ext4-partitions-on-windows)

Most answers are very old, but this one was written this year. If you don't mind using non-free (but at no cost for personal use) software, maybe Paragon's software will help you:

https://superuser.com/a/756944/158390

Comment: so there is no way to detect ext4 in in windows, you almost solved the question thanks :D

Comment: Does the link I provided (summarized by MHK in the other answer) not help you to get Ubuntu back as a boot option?

Comment: No NO I can use windows and as well as ubuntu now. But windows doesnt recognizes the ubuntu hdd which is ext4 , is there a way that I can acccess files from ext4 partition from windows ?

Comment: You're welcome. I hope you have a great experience with Ubuntu. I left the Windows world 14 years ago and haven't missed it one bit!

Answer (score 2):

Boot into ubuntu on a live cd/usb

Add boot repair disk

Open Terminal

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair

sudo sed 's/trusty/saucy/g' -i /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yannubuntu-boot-repair-trusty.list

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair

Run Boot Repair Application

Select Recommended repair option

Reboot and select OS you want

This will rebuild Grub and give you access to all Operating Systems

Comment: Thank you but the person above solved my question,